# Cannot run simplest command in a container

Tags: windows, docker

I am new to docker and this is supposed to be running Windows containers in Windows machine.
I have just started, but I am not really able to run even simplest command. Here is me using nanoserver to run echo:

```
PS C:\git\hello> docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903 echo "hello"
docker: Error response from daemon: container c828528b48b30dfbbcd48522199c5938dd0363f63df1b328c1d92b0ea23acee8 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6EFA3B3A7: (caller: 00007FF6EF9EE70B) Exception(2) tid(388) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
    CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
 Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] extra info: {"CommandLine":"echo hello","User":"ContainerUser","WorkingDirectory":"C:\\","CreateStdInPipe":true,"CreateStdOutPipe":true,"CreateStdErrPipe":true,"ConsoleSize":[0,0]}.
```

When i switch command to ipconfig for example it is working:

```
PS C:\git\hello> docker run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903 ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : xxx.xxx
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xx::xx:xx:xx:xx%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : xx.xx.xx.xxx
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : xx.xx.xx.xx
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : xx.xx.xx.xx
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

In this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8352b9b5-03ae-438c-80c7-6412631d490f/cant-run-powershell-command-in-nano-server-container-image-on-ws2019-datacenter?forum=windowscontainers) I found that the image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver` has no powershell included.

If you need to execute command I suggest to run the `mcr.microsoft.com/powershell` instead.

After the `docker run mcr.microsoft.com/powershell` command (notice here that i did not add any command at the end),

Do

`docker ps` in order to get your container id that has been launched by the `docker run` command.

Then just do a `docker exec` command

`docker exec -it <container_id> powershell.exe`

The `-it` flag here, basically bind the standard input `stdin` and standard output `stdout` of your running container to your shell.
In this way you will be able to interact with your container and should be able to execute any powershell command there (which will be executed inside your container)

A better way could be to tag your image with a name first :

`docker run --name myserver mcr.microsoft.com/powershell`

And then directly execute

`docker exec -it myserver powershell.exe`

But a `docker ps` is always a good thing to do before executing commands in order to be sure that you have a running container.

Comment: Unfortunately issue persists:
`C:\git\hello> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                       COMMAND                    CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
b0a6a6a081b0   mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1903   "c:\\windows\\system32…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes             serv
C:\git\hello> docker exec -it serv powershell.exe
container b0a6a6a081b0006bddef46554d82d5c40972e17a27d01dad9033e28db00a0177 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)`

Comment: @johnnymccloud I updated my answer. Let me know if it does help you

Comment: Still same :(
`PS C:\Users\janchm> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND      CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
ff2427e2eb5b   mcr.microsoft.com/powershell   "pwsh.exe"   2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes             power
PS C:\Users\janchm> docker exec power echo "hello"
container ff2427e2eb5bd4cb35b6903f89148b999456c13ba6f21d6eed074000562f1321 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)`

Comment: Your `exec` command is wrong please try : `docker exec -it power powershell.exe` or `docker exec -it power pwsh.exe` and only then you should see the powershell terminal open and could be able to enter powershell commands